# Add custom font to android application

Tags: java, android, android-fonts

I am trying to add custom font to my android application. This is my code. Can anyone tell me where i'm wrong ?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FontTest);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext()
                .getAssets(), "fonts/snap-itc.ttf");
        textview.setTypeface(tf);
    }
```

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     tools:context=".MainActivity" >
>     <TextView 
>         android:id="@+id/FontTest"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Font Test"
>         android:textSize="50px"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: The code is fine...are u getting any kind of error or Exception post that

Comment: Error is "native fonts cannot be set".

Comment: Also, what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/snap-itc.ttf");
```

Instead Of:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext()
                .getAssets(), "fonts/snap-itc.ttf");
```

Comment: Not work again. Error is "native fonts cannot be set"

Comment: Put your ttf file in assets folder only. then fetch it as `Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "snap-itc.ttf");`.

Answer (score 0):

It's might be obvious, but make sure you have an **/assets/fonts** folder in your project directory, and your custom font is there. Also, check for correct spelling of your font (+ is it uppercase/lowercase) and correct the spelling in your code.

It might also mean that the font itself is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

**add fonts in your application like**

```
 TextView txtvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewname);

 Typeface typface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/burmese.ttf");

  txtvw.setTypeface(typface);
```